# "TypeError: _this3.getEvents is not a function"

Tags: vue.js

Inside the create, post, delete methods, I call the getEvents method, and an error occurs that this is not a method, perhaps the entry is incorrect(then how is it correct)?

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
        async getEvents(context) {
            var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/');
            var data = await response.json()
            context('getEvents', data)
        },
        async createEvent(context) {
            await this.getEvents();
            await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ event: context.state.event })
            });
            await this.getEvents();
            context.commit('createEvent', context.state.event)
        },
        async editEvent(context) {
            await this.getEvents();
            await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/${context.state.event.id}/`, {
                method: 'put',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ event: context.state.event })
            });
            await this.getEvents();
            context.state.event = {};
        },
        async deleteEvent(context) {
            await this.getEvents();
            await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/${context.state.event.id}/`, {
                method: 'delete',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ event: context.state.event })
            });
            await this.getEvents();
        },


        submitForm(context) {
            if (context.state.event.id === undefined) {
                this.createEvent();
            } else {
                this.editEvent();
            }
        },

});
```

And the components themselves are not output

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not usually use `Vuex` (but I know js), you can do something as follows:

```js
async function internalGetEvents(context) {
  var response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest/');
  var data = await response.json()
  context('getEvents', data)
}

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    async getEvents(context) {
      return internalGetEvents(context);
    },
    async createEvent(context) {
      await internalGetEvents(context);
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
};
```

P.S.: also you are not passing the context...maybe the problem is there.

Comment: In vue, to create global functions, define a separate js file and import it to vue:
import { isMonthEqualNow, isWeekEqualNow, isDayEqualNow } from '@/globalFunctions.js'

Comment: you can do wait you say but is not mandatory at all

Answer (score 0):

You can access other functions inside actions using the following line:

```
context.dispatch('functionName');
```

Comment: is `dispatch` async? because I imagine you have to await before going on with the rest

Comment: @niccord, Yeah in my case I use await, but I wrote common case for use(without await)